# Papi_avail no events available - Unknown libpfm4 related error

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, papi

I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu 20 on an AMD Ryzen 5000 series. I installed papi tools 6 by following the install instructions. The installation was succsessful and I verified the installed version:

```
$ sudo papi_version
PAPI Version: 6.0.0.0
```

Then, when I verified the available events, I got none:

```
$ sudo papi_avail
Available PAPI preset and user defined events plus hardware information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI version             : 6.0.0.0
Operating system         : Linux 5.8.0-55-generic
Vendor string and code   : AuthenticAMD (2, 0x2)
Model string and code    : AMD Ryzen 9 5900 12-Core Processor (33, 0x21)
CPU revision             : 0.000000
CPUID                    : Family/Model/Stepping 25/33/0, 0x19/0x21/0x00
CPU Max MHz              : 6084
CPU Min MHz              : 2200
Total cores              : 24
SMT threads per core     : 2
Cores per socket         : 12
Sockets                  : 1
Cores per NUMA region    : 24
NUMA regions             : 1
Running in a VM          : no
Number Hardware Counters : 0
Max Multiplex Counters   : 384
Fast counter read (rdpmc): yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================================================================================
  PAPI Preset Events
================================================================================
    Name        Code    Avail Deriv Description (Note)
PAPI_L1_DCM  0x80000000  No    No   Level 1 data cache misses
PAPI_L1_ICM  0x80000001  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L2_DCM  0x80000002  No    No   Level 2 data cache misses
PAPI_L2_ICM  0x80000003  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L3_DCM  0x80000004  No    No   Level 3 data cache misses
PAPI_L3_ICM  0x80000005  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L1_TCM  0x80000006  No    No   Level 1 cache misses
PAPI_L2_TCM  0x80000007  No    No   Level 2 cache misses
PAPI_L3_TCM  0x80000008  No    No   Level 3 cache misses
PAPI_CA_SNP  0x80000009  No    No   Requests for a snoop
PAPI_CA_SHR  0x8000000a  No    No   Requests for exclusive access to shared cache line
PAPI_CA_CLN  0x8000000b  No    No   Requests for exclusive access to clean cache line
PAPI_CA_INV  0x8000000c  No    No   Requests for cache line invalidation
PAPI_CA_ITV  0x8000000d  No    No   Requests for cache line intervention
PAPI_L3_LDM  0x8000000e  No    No   Level 3 load misses
PAPI_L3_STM  0x8000000f  No    No   Level 3 store misses
PAPI_BRU_IDL 0x80000010  No    No   Cycles branch units are idle
PAPI_FXU_IDL 0x80000011  No    No   Cycles integer units are idle
PAPI_FPU_IDL 0x80000012  No    No   Cycles floating point units are idle
PAPI_LSU_IDL 0x80000013  No    No   Cycles load/store units are idle
PAPI_TLB_DM  0x80000014  No    No   Data translation lookaside buffer misses
PAPI_TLB_IM  0x80000015  No    No   Instruction translation lookaside buffer misses
PAPI_TLB_TL  0x80000016  No    No   Total translation lookaside buffer misses
PAPI_L1_LDM  0x80000017  No    No   Level 1 load misses
PAPI_L1_STM  0x80000018  No    No   Level 1 store misses
PAPI_L2_LDM  0x80000019  No    No   Level 2 load misses
PAPI_L2_STM  0x8000001a  No    No   Level 2 store misses
PAPI_BTAC_M  0x8000001b  No    No   Branch target address cache misses
PAPI_PRF_DM  0x8000001c  No    No   Data prefetch cache misses
PAPI_L3_DCH  0x8000001d  No    No   Level 3 data cache hits
PAPI_TLB_SD  0x8000001e  No    No   Translation lookaside buffer shootdowns
PAPI_CSR_FAL 0x8000001f  No    No   Failed store conditional instructions
PAPI_CSR_SUC 0x80000020  No    No   Successful store conditional instructions
PAPI_CSR_TOT 0x80000021  No    No   Total store conditional instructions
PAPI_MEM_SCY 0x80000022  No    No   Cycles Stalled Waiting for memory accesses
PAPI_MEM_RCY 0x80000023  No    No   Cycles Stalled Waiting for memory Reads
PAPI_MEM_WCY 0x80000024  No    No   Cycles Stalled Waiting for memory writes
PAPI_STL_ICY 0x80000025  No    No   Cycles with no instruction issue
PAPI_FUL_ICY 0x80000026  No    No   Cycles with maximum instruction issue
PAPI_STL_CCY 0x80000027  No    No   Cycles with no instructions completed
PAPI_FUL_CCY 0x80000028  No    No   Cycles with maximum instructions completed
PAPI_HW_INT  0x80000029  No    No   Hardware interrupts
PAPI_BR_UCN  0x8000002a  No    No   Unconditional branch instructions
PAPI_BR_CN   0x8000002b  No    No   Conditional branch instructions
PAPI_BR_TKN  0x8000002c  No    No   Conditional branch instructions taken
PAPI_BR_NTK  0x8000002d  No    No   Conditional branch instructions not taken
PAPI_BR_MSP  0x8000002e  No    No   Conditional branch instructions mispredicted
PAPI_BR_PRC  0x8000002f  No    No   Conditional branch instructions correctly predicted
PAPI_FMA_INS 0x80000030  No    No   FMA instructions completed
PAPI_TOT_IIS 0x80000031  No    No   Instructions issued
PAPI_TOT_INS 0x80000032  No    No   Instructions completed
PAPI_INT_INS 0x80000033  No    No   Integer instructions
PAPI_FP_INS  0x80000034  No    No   Floating point instructions
PAPI_LD_INS  0x80000035  No    No   Load instructions
PAPI_SR_INS  0x80000036  No    No   Store instructions
PAPI_BR_INS  0x80000037  No    No   Branch instructions
PAPI_VEC_INS 0x80000038  No    No   Vector/SIMD instructions (could include integer)
PAPI_RES_STL 0x80000039  No    No   Cycles stalled on any resource
PAPI_FP_STAL 0x8000003a  No    No   Cycles the FP unit(s) are stalled
PAPI_TOT_CYC 0x8000003b  No    No   Total cycles
PAPI_LST_INS 0x8000003c  No    No   Load/store instructions completed
PAPI_SYC_INS 0x8000003d  No    No   Synchronization instructions completed
PAPI_L1_DCH  0x8000003e  No    No   Level 1 data cache hits
PAPI_L2_DCH  0x8000003f  No    No   Level 2 data cache hits
PAPI_L1_DCA  0x80000040  No    No   Level 1 data cache accesses
PAPI_L2_DCA  0x80000041  No    No   Level 2 data cache accesses
PAPI_L3_DCA  0x80000042  No    No   Level 3 data cache accesses
PAPI_L1_DCR  0x80000043  No    No   Level 1 data cache reads
PAPI_L2_DCR  0x80000044  No    No   Level 2 data cache reads
PAPI_L3_DCR  0x80000045  No    No   Level 3 data cache reads
PAPI_L1_DCW  0x80000046  No    No   Level 1 data cache writes
PAPI_L2_DCW  0x80000047  No    No   Level 2 data cache writes
PAPI_L3_DCW  0x80000048  No    No   Level 3 data cache writes
PAPI_L1_ICH  0x80000049  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache hits
PAPI_L2_ICH  0x8000004a  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache hits
PAPI_L3_ICH  0x8000004b  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache hits
PAPI_L1_ICA  0x8000004c  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache accesses
PAPI_L2_ICA  0x8000004d  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache accesses
PAPI_L3_ICA  0x8000004e  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache accesses
PAPI_L1_ICR  0x8000004f  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache reads
PAPI_L2_ICR  0x80000050  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache reads
PAPI_L3_ICR  0x80000051  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache reads
PAPI_L1_ICW  0x80000052  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache writes
PAPI_L2_ICW  0x80000053  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache writes
PAPI_L3_ICW  0x80000054  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache writes
PAPI_L1_TCH  0x80000055  No    No   Level 1 total cache hits
PAPI_L2_TCH  0x80000056  No    No   Level 2 total cache hits
PAPI_L3_TCH  0x80000057  No    No   Level 3 total cache hits
PAPI_L1_TCA  0x80000058  No    No   Level 1 total cache accesses
PAPI_L2_TCA  0x80000059  No    No   Level 2 total cache accesses
PAPI_L3_TCA  0x8000005a  No    No   Level 3 total cache accesses
PAPI_L1_TCR  0x8000005b  No    No   Level 1 total cache reads
PAPI_L2_TCR  0x8000005c  No    No   Level 2 total cache reads
PAPI_L3_TCR  0x8000005d  No    No   Level 3 total cache reads
PAPI_L1_TCW  0x8000005e  No    No   Level 1 total cache writes
PAPI_L2_TCW  0x8000005f  No    No   Level 2 total cache writes
PAPI_L3_TCW  0x80000060  No    No   Level 3 total cache writes
PAPI_FML_INS 0x80000061  No    No   Floating point multiply instructions
PAPI_FAD_INS 0x80000062  No    No   Floating point add instructions
PAPI_FDV_INS 0x80000063  No    No   Floating point divide instructions
PAPI_FSQ_INS 0x80000064  No    No   Floating point square root instructions
PAPI_FNV_INS 0x80000065  No    No   Floating point inverse instructions
PAPI_FP_OPS  0x80000066  No    No   Floating point operations
PAPI_SP_OPS  0x80000067  No    No   Floating point operations; optimized to count scaled single precision vector operations
PAPI_DP_OPS  0x80000068  No    No   Floating point operations; optimized to count scaled double precision vector operations
PAPI_VEC_SP  0x80000069  No    No   Single precision vector/SIMD instructions
PAPI_VEC_DP  0x8000006a  No    No   Double precision vector/SIMD instructions
PAPI_REF_CYC 0x8000006b  No    No   Reference clock cycles
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Of 108 possible events, 0 are available, of which 0 are derived.

No events detected!  Check papi_component_avail to find out why.
```

So I followed the instructions and I ran the papi_component_avail:

```
papi_component_avail
Available components and hardware information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI version             : 6.0.0.0
Operating system         : Linux 5.8.0-55-generic
Vendor string and code   : AuthenticAMD (2, 0x2)
Model string and code    : AMD Ryzen 9 5900 12-Core Processor (33, 0x21)
CPU revision             : 0.000000
CPUID                    : Family/Model/Stepping 25/33/0, 0x19/0x21/0x00
CPU Max MHz              : 6084
CPU Min MHz              : 2200
Total cores              : 24
SMT threads per core     : 2
Cores per socket         : 12
Sockets                  : 1
Cores per NUMA region    : 24
NUMA regions             : 1
Running in a VM          : no
Number Hardware Counters : 0
Max Multiplex Counters   : 384
Fast counter read (rdpmc): yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compiled-in components:
Name:   perf_event              Linux perf_event CPU counters
   \-> Disabled: Unknown libpfm4 related error
Name:   perf_event_uncore       Linux perf_event CPU uncore and northbridge
   \-> Disabled: No uncore PMUs or events found

Active components:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried applying the fix explained in the stack overflow question [papi_avail: No events available - 32308175](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308175/papi-avail-no-events-available) which in the past has worked on my Ubuntu 18 running an Intel 6700HQ, but with no avail here. Of course, the problem descriptions were different.I am uncertain on how to resolve the "Unknown libpfm4 related error" error.

I also tried installing the current availabe version of Papi using  the "apt get install papi tools"

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install papi-tools
```

The installation went fine but I keep getting the same errore messages. What have I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU is part of the [AMD ZEN3 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_3). `libpfm4` seems to support this CPU architecture family from `v4.12.0`. If you have `papi` version `6.0.0.1` or less, it comes with a built-in version of `libpfm4` that is older than `v4.12.0` so I suppose `papi` is expected not to work in that case?

Nevertheless, we are still experiencing the same issue when installing the `master` branch of `papi` (that comes with a `libpfm4` version that should support `AMD ZEN3` according to [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/icl/papi/src/master/src/libpfm4/)).