# papi_avail No events detected! - Error libpfm4 no default PMU found

Tags: papi

I tried to make PAPI on my Fedora 37.
Machine specification:
Linux fedora-hp 6.0.9-300.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 16 17:36:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Getting FAILED tests when using `make test`.
It gives the following output

```
make -C testlib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devanshjain/Downloads/papi/src/testlib'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devanshjain/Downloads/papi/src/testlib'
make -C validation_tests
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devanshjain/Downloads/papi/src/validation_tests'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devanshjain/Downloads/papi/src/validation_tests'
make -C ctests
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/devanshjain/Downloads/papi/src/ctests'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/devanshjain/Downloads/papi/src/ctests'
ctests/zero
PAPI Error: Error Code -25,Component containing event is disabled
Trouble adding PAPI_TOT_CYC: Component containing event is disabled
SKIPPED
```

I tried applying the fix explained in the stack overflow question
[papi_avail: No events available - 32308175](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67995139/papi-avail-no-events-available-unknown-libpfm4-related-error). But I was still getting the same error again.

Output when using `./utils/papi_avail`

```
Available PAPI preset and user defined events plus hardware information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI version             : 7.0.0.0
Operating system         : Linux 6.0.9-300.fc37.x86_64
Vendor string and code   : AuthenticAMD (2, 0x2)
Model string and code    : AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics (80, 0x50)
CPU revision             : 0.000000
CPUID                    : Family/Model/Stepping 25/80/0, 0x19/0x50/0x00
CPU Max MHz              : 4280
CPU Min MHz              : 400
Total cores              : 12
SMT threads per core     : 2
Cores per socket         : 6
Sockets                  : 1
Cores per NUMA region    : 12
NUMA regions             : 1
Running in a VM          : no
Number Hardware Counters : 0
Max Multiplex Counters   : 384
Fast counter read (rdpmc): yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

================================================================================
  PAPI Preset Events
================================================================================
    Name        Code    Avail Deriv Description (Note)
PAPI_L1_DCM  0x80000000  No    No   Level 1 data cache misses
PAPI_L1_ICM  0x80000001  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L2_DCM  0x80000002  No    No   Level 2 data cache misses
PAPI_L2_ICM  0x80000003  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L3_DCM  0x80000004  No    No   Level 3 data cache misses
PAPI_L3_ICM  0x80000005  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache misses
PAPI_L1_TCM  0x80000006  No    No   Level 1 cache misses
PAPI_L2_TCM  0x80000007  No    No   Level 2 cache misses
PAPI_L3_TCM  0x80000008  No    No   Level 3 cache misses
PAPI_CA_SNP  0x80000009  No    No   Requests for a snoop
PAPI_CA_SHR  0x8000000a  No    No   Requests for exclusive access to shared cache line
PAPI_CA_CLN  0x8000000b  No    No   Requests for exclusive access to clean cache line
PAPI_CA_INV  0x8000000c  No    No   Requests for cache line invalidation
PAPI_CA_ITV  0x8000000d  No    No   Requests for cache line intervention
PAPI_L3_LDM  0x8000000e  No    No   Level 3 load misses
PAPI_L3_STM  0x8000000f  No    No   Level 3 store misses
PAPI_BRU_IDL 0x80000010  No    No   Cycles branch units are idle
PAPI_FXU_IDL 0x80000011  No    No   Cycles integer units are idle
PAPI_FPU_IDL 0x80000012  No    No   Cycles floating point units are idle
PAPI_LSU_IDL 0x80000013  No    No   Cycles load/store units are idle
PAPI_TLB_DM  0x80000014  No    No   Data translation lookaside buffer misses
PAPI_TLB_IM  0x80000015  No    No   Instruction translation lookaside buffer misses
PAPI_TLB_TL  0x80000016  No    No   Total translation lookaside buffer misses
PAPI_L1_LDM  0x80000017  No    No   Level 1 load misses
PAPI_L1_STM  0x80000018  No    No   Level 1 store misses
PAPI_L2_LDM  0x80000019  No    No   Level 2 load misses
PAPI_L2_STM  0x8000001a  No    No   Level 2 store misses
PAPI_BTAC_M  0x8000001b  No    No   Branch target address cache misses
PAPI_PRF_DM  0x8000001c  No    No   Data prefetch cache misses
PAPI_L3_DCH  0x8000001d  No    No   Level 3 data cache hits
PAPI_TLB_SD  0x8000001e  No    No   Translation lookaside buffer shootdowns
PAPI_CSR_FAL 0x8000001f  No    No   Failed store conditional instructions
PAPI_CSR_SUC 0x80000020  No    No   Successful store conditional instructions
PAPI_CSR_TOT 0x80000021  No    No   Total store conditional instructions
PAPI_MEM_SCY 0x80000022  No    No   Cycles Stalled Waiting for memory accesses
PAPI_MEM_RCY 0x80000023  No    No   Cycles Stalled Waiting for memory Reads
PAPI_MEM_WCY 0x80000024  No    No   Cycles Stalled Waiting for memory writes
PAPI_STL_ICY 0x80000025  No    No   Cycles with no instruction issue
PAPI_FUL_ICY 0x80000026  No    No   Cycles with maximum instruction issue
PAPI_STL_CCY 0x80000027  No    No   Cycles with no instructions completed
PAPI_FUL_CCY 0x80000028  No    No   Cycles with maximum instructions completed
PAPI_HW_INT  0x80000029  No    No   Hardware interrupts
PAPI_BR_UCN  0x8000002a  No    No   Unconditional branch instructions
PAPI_BR_CN   0x8000002b  No    No   Conditional branch instructions
PAPI_BR_TKN  0x8000002c  No    No   Conditional branch instructions taken
PAPI_BR_NTK  0x8000002d  No    No   Conditional branch instructions not taken
PAPI_BR_MSP  0x8000002e  No    No   Conditional branch instructions mispredicted
PAPI_BR_PRC  0x8000002f  No    No   Conditional branch instructions correctly predicted
PAPI_FMA_INS 0x80000030  No    No   FMA instructions completed
PAPI_TOT_IIS 0x80000031  No    No   Instructions issued
PAPI_TOT_INS 0x80000032  No    No   Instructions completed
PAPI_INT_INS 0x80000033  No    No   Integer instructions
PAPI_FP_INS  0x80000034  No    No   Floating point instructions
PAPI_LD_INS  0x80000035  No    No   Load instructions
PAPI_SR_INS  0x80000036  No    No   Store instructions
PAPI_BR_INS  0x80000037  No    No   Branch instructions
PAPI_VEC_INS 0x80000038  No    No   Vector/SIMD instructions (could include integer)
PAPI_RES_STL 0x80000039  No    No   Cycles stalled on any resource
PAPI_FP_STAL 0x8000003a  No    No   Cycles the FP unit(s) are stalled
PAPI_TOT_CYC 0x8000003b  No    No   Total cycles
PAPI_LST_INS 0x8000003c  No    No   Load/store instructions completed
PAPI_SYC_INS 0x8000003d  No    No   Synchronization instructions completed
PAPI_L1_DCH  0x8000003e  No    No   Level 1 data cache hits
PAPI_L2_DCH  0x8000003f  No    No   Level 2 data cache hits
PAPI_L1_DCA  0x80000040  No    No   Level 1 data cache accesses
PAPI_L2_DCA  0x80000041  No    No   Level 2 data cache accesses
PAPI_L3_DCA  0x80000042  No    No   Level 3 data cache accesses
PAPI_L1_DCR  0x80000043  No    No   Level 1 data cache reads
PAPI_L2_DCR  0x80000044  No    No   Level 2 data cache reads
PAPI_L3_DCR  0x80000045  No    No   Level 3 data cache reads
PAPI_L1_DCW  0x80000046  No    No   Level 1 data cache writes
PAPI_L2_DCW  0x80000047  No    No   Level 2 data cache writes
PAPI_L3_DCW  0x80000048  No    No   Level 3 data cache writes
PAPI_L1_ICH  0x80000049  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache hits
PAPI_L2_ICH  0x8000004a  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache hits
PAPI_L3_ICH  0x8000004b  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache hits
PAPI_L1_ICA  0x8000004c  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache accesses
PAPI_L2_ICA  0x8000004d  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache accesses
PAPI_L3_ICA  0x8000004e  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache accesses
PAPI_L1_ICR  0x8000004f  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache reads
PAPI_L2_ICR  0x80000050  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache reads
PAPI_L3_ICR  0x80000051  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache reads
PAPI_L1_ICW  0x80000052  No    No   Level 1 instruction cache writes
PAPI_L2_ICW  0x80000053  No    No   Level 2 instruction cache writes
PAPI_L3_ICW  0x80000054  No    No   Level 3 instruction cache writes
PAPI_L1_TCH  0x80000055  No    No   Level 1 total cache hits
PAPI_L2_TCH  0x80000056  No    No   Level 2 total cache hits
PAPI_L3_TCH  0x80000057  No    No   Level 3 total cache hits
PAPI_L1_TCA  0x80000058  No    No   Level 1 total cache accesses
PAPI_L2_TCA  0x80000059  No    No   Level 2 total cache accesses
PAPI_L3_TCA  0x8000005a  No    No   Level 3 total cache accesses
PAPI_L1_TCR  0x8000005b  No    No   Level 1 total cache reads
PAPI_L2_TCR  0x8000005c  No    No   Level 2 total cache reads
PAPI_L3_TCR  0x8000005d  No    No   Level 3 total cache reads
PAPI_L1_TCW  0x8000005e  No    No   Level 1 total cache writes
PAPI_L2_TCW  0x8000005f  No    No   Level 2 total cache writes
PAPI_L3_TCW  0x80000060  No    No   Level 3 total cache writes
PAPI_FML_INS 0x80000061  No    No   Floating point multiply instructions
PAPI_FAD_INS 0x80000062  No    No   Floating point add instructions
PAPI_FDV_INS 0x80000063  No    No   Floating point divide instructions
PAPI_FSQ_INS 0x80000064  No    No   Floating point square root instructions
PAPI_FNV_INS 0x80000065  No    No   Floating point inverse instructions
PAPI_FP_OPS  0x80000066  No    No   Floating point operations
PAPI_SP_OPS  0x80000067  No    No   Floating point operations; optimized to count scaled single precision vector operations
PAPI_DP_OPS  0x80000068  No    No   Floating point operations; optimized to count scaled double precision vector operations
PAPI_VEC_SP  0x80000069  No    No   Single precision vector/SIMD instructions
PAPI_VEC_DP  0x8000006a  No    No   Double precision vector/SIMD instructions
PAPI_REF_CYC 0x8000006b  No    No   Reference clock cycles
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Of 108 possible events, 0 are available, of which 0 are derived.

No events detected!  Check papi_component_avail to find out why.
```

Output when using `./utils/papi_component_avail`

```
Available components and hardware information.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAPI version             : 7.0.0.0
Operating system         : Linux 6.0.9-300.fc37.x86_64
Vendor string and code   : AuthenticAMD (2, 0x2)
Model string and code    : AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics (80, 0x50)
CPU revision             : 0.000000
CPUID                    : Family/Model/Stepping 25/80/0, 0x19/0x50/0x00
CPU Max MHz              : 4280
CPU Min MHz              : 400
Total cores              : 12
SMT threads per core     : 2
Cores per socket         : 6
Sockets                  : 1
Cores per NUMA region    : 12
NUMA regions             : 1
Running in a VM          : no
Number Hardware Counters : 0
Max Multiplex Counters   : 384
Fast counter read (rdpmc): yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compiled-in components:
Name:   perf_event              Linux perf_event CPU counters
   \-> Disabled: Error libpfm4 no default PMU found
Name:   perf_event_uncore       Linux perf_event CPU uncore and northbridge
   \-> Disabled: No uncore PMUs or events found
Name:   sysdetect               System info detection component

Active components:
Name:   sysdetect               System info detection component
                                Native: 0, Preset: 0, Counters: 0


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify, what exact PMU you want to use by [LIBPFM_FORCE_PMU](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/libpfm.3.html) environment variable. `LIBPFM_FORCE_PMU=amd64 papi_avail` command works in my case.